# Load WordPress functions outside WordPress files in Add on Domain

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to load `wp-load.php` file from WordPress in my ADD ON DOMAIN. I am using `require_once('./wp-load.php');` to load `wp-load.php` and `get_header();` to load header in my php file. Primary Domain is loading WordPress functions fine but add domain is not, it is not throwing up any error.

```
<?php require_once("../wp-load.php"); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

I am expecting to load WordPress function in my php file on Add domain like the way Primary domain loads

Answer (score 0):

When you view a WordPress page, the first file called is index.php.

**Method 1:**

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require ('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

The blog header file (that queues up the rest of WordPress) loads `wp-load.php` directly and fires up WordPress itself. Here's most of `wp-blog-header.php`:

**Method 2:**

```
if ( !isset($wp_did_header) ) {

    $wp_did_header = true;

    require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

    wp();

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

}
```

So the difference between   two methods is ... what's loaded.

Method 1 is exactly what WordPress does to load itself (with the exception of turning themes off). So if you need all of WordPress and want to fire all of the default hooks/actions, go with that route.

Method 2 is just a further step down the line. It loads all of WordPress, but doesn't call wp() or invoke the template loader (used by themes). Method 2 will be a little lighter-weight, but should give you the same functionality.

Comment: Everything works fine with your code even mine in ```PRIMARY DOMAIN``` . I need also the same functions to work on ADD ON DOMAIN which resides on the same cPanel as PRIMARY DOMAIN.